# How do I keep percent signs (%) copying from LPCTSTR to LPTSTR?

Tags: c++, c, buffer, lptstr

I am a beginner in this and after a lot of frustration I finally had the courage to ask to all of you, the true professionals.

I need to keep all the percent signs (%) I receive from a LPCTSTR when I copy it to a LPTSTR. After some researching and trying, I came with this:

```
LPCTSTR lpRemapping; // Contains a string with percents (%) in it
size_t nSize = _tcsclen(lpRemapping) + 1;
LPTSTR lpBuffer = new TCHAR[nSize];
errno_t nResult = _tcsncpy_s(lpBuffer, nSize, lpRemapping, ((size_t)-1));
for (int currentChar = 0; currentChar < nSize; currentChar++) {
    if (lpRemapping[currentChar] == '%') {
        lpBuffer[currentChar] = '%%';
    }
}
```

But it seems I am still losing the percent signs in the process. I have read a lot of answers telling me to use %% but I am doing something wrong here and I don't know what it is.

I do not control the string I am receiving and some of them will definitely contain the percent sign (%).

I really appreciate your time and I hope you can bring me some light in this matter.

Comment: I think there is nothing special about `'%'` except in the format strings of `printf` and `scanf` family.

Comment: this `'%%'` is not a character. Also if you want to replace a single character with two characters you have to shift all following characters otherwise eg `"asd%asd"` will become `"asd%%sd"`

Comment: You need to resize your buffer depending on how many `%` you have in your string, because the new mapped `%%` adds a char to your string.

Comment: The code in the `for` loop is simply wrong. Please confirm that your code is supposed to transform a string like `"ABC % DEF % GHI"` into `"ABC %% DEF %% GHI"`.

Comment: Also `'%%'` is not a pair of percent signs.    It is a multi-character literal, which has type `int` and a value that is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I apologize for the lack of clearness. My code is supposed to read "ABC%DEF%GHI" from LPCTSTR lpRemapping and keep exactly the same "ABC%DEF%GHI" in LPTSTR lpBuffer, but as user463035818 stated, I am getting "ABCEFHI" in LPTSTR lpBuffer

Comment: Is that because you check that by printing that string with `printf(str)`? Don't do that, because you never know what format specifiers (for which you don't provide arguments) it contains. To print a string, use `printf("%s", str)` or (with a new-line), `puts(str)`. There shouldn't be anything special about copying.

Comment: Complement to M Oehm's comment: you don't need any remapping at all. Just use the string pointed by`lpRemapping` as is.

Comment: Using `TCHAR*` has two big problems: it's a Windows 95 workaround; we switched to plain `WCHAR` about 2 decades ago. And since this is C++ code, we'd use `std::wstring`.